# acts-as-taggable-on and select fields

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm using the [ActsAsTaggableOn](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) gem for Rails 3.0 and everything works fine.

Now I'm trying to speed up some queries selecting only some fields with ActiveRecord:

```
@items = Item.select("items.id, items.title").where("items.title IS NOT NULL)

@items.tag_counts
```

But I got this error back from MySQL:

```
> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s): SELECT
SQL_NO_CACHE tags.*, COUNT(*) AS count FROM `tags` LEFT OUTER JOIN taggings ON tags.id =
taggings.tag_id AND taggings.context = 'tags' INNER JOIN items ON items.id = 
taggings.taggable_id WHERE (taggings.taggable_type = 'Item') AND (taggings.taggable_id
IN(SELECT items.id, items.title, items.id FROM `items` WHERE (title IS NOT NULL)))
GROUP BY tags.id, tags.name HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
```

Instead if I regularly call tag_counts on the collection it works:

```
@items = Item.where("items.title IS NOT NULL)

@items.tag_counts
```

Any ideas for a simple workaround without editing the gem?

Comment: Perhaps you need the instances of Item not just id and title.